# Check directory exists on remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, shell-script

I am trying to check if directory exists on remote server using sshpass command with ssh. This is my code

```
if [sshpass -p 'xxxx' ssh admin@xx.xx.xx.xx '[ -d /var/www/html/Dirct1/Backup/11-12-12]']; then
echo '1'
else
echo '2'
fi
```

I am getting an error test: 3: test: [sshpass: not found. test is my script file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a space after your bracket: `if [ sshpass ...`. like wise the closing brackets may require more spaces. But normaly to test the return code of a command you don't put the brackets, these are replaced by the `test` command under the hood: `if [ 1 -eq 2 ]` is actually(*) `if test 1 -eq 2`. If can also be a lot simpler/more readable to test the return code afterwards:

```
sshpass -p 'xxxx' ssh admin@xx.xx.xx.xx '[ -d /var/www/html/Dirct1/Backup/11-12-12]'
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then 
    echo '1'
else
    echo '2' 
fi
```

(*) and actually `test` is replaced by a bash built-in